# Add a button to an e-mail which runs a macro when clicked

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

I'd like to send a friend an e-mail that has a clickable button in the message body... The button will run a macro.

I know you can do macros on your side of things, such as:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox "Hey Look a Macro!"
End Sub
```

Which will run a macro when I load a new e-mail.

I'd like to attach this macro to run when the button in the e-mail I sent is clicked on. Btw, I don't mind if the receiving user receives warnings about the macro, just so long as they can execute it via a button

I'd like to know:

- Is that possible?
- How do I do it?

Thanks!

---

Edit: All I see are ways to run a macro on my side, not send an executable macro to someone else

[image]

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: @CharlieRB I've researched a lot but only found ways to run a macro for myself, not send an executable macro to someone else. I've updated above with the stuff I see

Comment: This will almost certainly not work, as this was a popular method of transfering viruses and malware for years. It can work, but befault MS Office and Windows will block these types of operations and / or throw messages and warnings.

Comment: @AthomSfere throw messages on my end and prevent transfer of macro, or just warnings to them (but they can still run the macro)?

Comment: Likely the latter, but your email provider might also block the attached code.

Comment: @AthomSfere okay, I'd like to try it anyway. Do you know how to 1) embed a button, 2) attach a macro to that button that they can run?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question with Outlook, so one option open to you is to use a custom form.  Distribution of that form is easier if you're in the same Exchange organization, although it's still possible if not.  There's an excellent writeup on [this page](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/tutorial-creating-and-distributing-custom-forms-with-outlook/), including creating the form and publishing it to other users.

Note that this option assumes that your sending the code is not a one-off occurrence, but rather something that you do on a regular basis.

You don't say much about your end goal, but if you're just trying to give your friend a button to press, other strategies could include using the (free) [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) to create a small VB EXE, and send it to your friend (in a zipped format to avoid the Outlook security warning) - or, just send them a dropbox link to the EXE itself.

Comment: Your tutorial link is dead